# How can multithreading help increase performance in this situation?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I have a piece of code like this:

```
while(){

    x = jdbc_readOperation();

    y = getTokens(x);

    jdbc_insertOperation(y);
}

public List<String> getTokens(String divText){
    List<String> tokenList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher subMatcher = Pattern.compile("\\[[^\\]]*]").matcher(divText);
    while (subMatcher.find()) {
        String token = subMatcher.group();
        tokenList.add(token);
    }
    return tokenList;
}
```

What I know is using multithreading can save time when one thread is get blocked by I/O or network. In this synchronous operations every step have to wait for its previous step get finished. What I want here is to maximize cpu utilization on **getTokens()**.

My first thought is put getTokens() in the run method of a class, and create multiple threads. But I think it will not work since it seems not able to get performance benefit by having multiple threads on pure computation operations.

Is adoption of multithreading going to help increase performance in this case? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: May we ask if the "stuff" being done by `some_stuff()` can be done in parallel?  Or, would it only make sense to have a single thread doing this?

Comment: There's no generic way to do this. It depends on exactly what `some_stuff()` does and exactly how this code is used in the program as a whole.

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity, some_stuff() is a string processing function with the only parameter coming from result of read operation. I've updated above. But I'm not sure is it can be done "in parallel" in this case, could you please elaborate on this? Thanks.

Comment: If `some_stuff()` depends entirely on `x`, and `y` depends entirely on `some_stuff()`, there is no way that parallelizing these three steps can improve performance. Possibly `some_stuff()` itself can be parallelized internally, but only you can know that.

Comment: How will the content of divText (or x if you will) - the input of the getTokens method look like? Will it be words seperated by spaces or other symbols?

Comment: Thanks, it is html code.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on the pace that jdbc_readOperation() produces data to be processed in comparison with the pace that getTokens(x) processes the data. Knowing that will help you figure out if multi-threading is going to help you.

You could try something like this (just for you to get the idea):

```
int workToBeDoneQueueSize = 1000;
int workDoneQueueSize = 1000;
BlockingQueue<String> workToBeDone = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(workToBeDoneQueueSize);
BlockingQueue<String> workDone = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(workDoneQueueSize);

new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        while (true) {
            workToBeDone.put(jdbc_readOperation());
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // handle InterruptedException here
    }
}).start();

int numOfWorkerThreads = 5; // just an example
for (int i = 0; i < numOfWorkerThreads; i++) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            while (true) {
                workDone.put(getTokens(workToBeDone.take()));
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // handle InterruptedException here
        }
    }).start();
}

new Thread(() -> {
    // you could improve this by making a batch operation
    try {
        while (true) {
            jdbc_insertOperation(workDone.take());
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // handle InterruptedException here
    }
}).start();
```

Or you could learn how to use the ThreadPoolExecutor. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. Is there any reason to use LinkedBlockingQueue rather than ArrayBlockingQueue in this case?

Comment: No, I don't think so, you could use either.

Answer (score 0):

Okay to speed up getTokens() you can split the inputted String divText by using String.substring() method. You split it into as many substrings as you will run Threads running the getTokens() method. Then every Thread will "run" on a certain substring of divText.

Creating more Threads than the CPU can handle should be avoided since context switches create inefficiency.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-

An alternative could be splitting the inputted String of getTokens with the String.split method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29 e.g. in case the text is made up of words seperated by spaces or other symbols. Then specific parts of the resulting String array could be passed to different Threads.

Comment: This won't work. How can you pre-determine from which points you should take substrings? Whenever you take substrings it may split strings which could have matched the pattern if they were kept as they are.

Comment: Good point, the splitting is a bit difficult. You would have to check what the maximum length of a word in the text could be and check that you do not cut there (before and after). Calculating an index for splitting can be done by orienting in this region specified by the maximum word length by checking for spaces if the divText contains words seperated by spaces.